# in appengine how can i have namespace based url routing?

Tags: google-app-engine, namespaces, url-routing

I'm trying to figure out how to change url routing based on namespace

Say I have myapp.x.com/apage and myapp.y.com/apage, I tried the code below but
it doesn't work because I presume the main.py is being cached

```
ns = namespace_manager.google_apps_namespace()
if ns == 'x.com'
    app = WSGIApplication([
        (r'/apage', 'my.module.XHandler'),
    ])
else:
    app = WSGIApplication([
        (r'/apage', 'my.module.YHandler'),
    ])
```

Is there any other way to do it besides of course turning each handler into a url router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own middleware that routes to different apps based on domain. See DomainMiddleware in [this blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/08/Using-BlobReader-wildcard-subdomains-and-webapp2) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, actually after seeing the way you did it and realizing that it was possible, I moved the routing code into the body of the main() function and it works. I guess appengine does not cache main.py but caches the main() function between requests.

Comment: App Engine keeps loaded modules loaded between requests. It doesn't re-execute the body of the module if your module has a main() function - instead, it just executes main(). I'd recommend writing middleware instead, though - it's more versatile and less kludgy.